# Check if last item if(in_array...)

Tags: php

I am showing stuff when found:

```
if(in_array("$id",$from-an-array)) {
    //show code

    //at last one found: show <hr> and continue
}
else { do other stuff }
```

After the last $id found in_array, I would like to show a one time break like `<hr>` - to break the run, and still continue the loop.

How do we know when we've reached this last item?

Comment: sidenote: `$from-an-array` if you really plan on using that; don't. It will throw an error. *Just saying*. PHP thinks you want to do math with the hyphens.

Comment: Thanks! But it is kinda like that: I want to know if the run has reached its last item.

Comment: ... You'll never find out though if it won't compile (which it wont... as @Fred-ii- has pointed out...)

Comment: Can you reword your question to help clarify? i.e. "break the run, ... continue the loop." There is no loop here, just an if,else.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want... "I want to know if the run has reached its last item" which last item? which run? With your code you only check if something ($id) is into an array.

Comment: It depends on how you loop the array.

Comment: You've an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to determine if a variable is the same as the last element in an array.

You can check your `$id` against the last item in the array using [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

```
if( $id == end($array) ) {
  //This is the last item
}
else {
   // ..
}
```

You could also use `===` (3 equal signs instead of 2) if you need to check that it's the exact same element, but that's not likely necessary.

Comment: Since OP's using `in_array()`, maybe they'll want to use `if(in_array($id, $array) && $id == end($array) )` - *Just my 2 cents* ;-) However, OP hasn't responded to your answer. Looks promising to me.

Comment: Thanks to @Fred -ii-  You nailed it with this one!

Comment: @KJS I need to add though; that this will fail `$id = "5"; $array = array("1", "3", "5a");` where 5 is treated as a string, as opposed to `$id = 5; $array = array("1", "3", "5a");` which will pass where 5 is treated as an integer; be careful "how" you use this. The use of a triple equal may be the key but will also fail on `$id = 5; $array = array("1", "3", "5");` when using `if( $id === end($array) )` where 5 is treated as an integer. Therefore, the array containing integers, should not be quoted. I.e.: `$array = array(1, 3, 5);`

Comment: Your help and answer gave some great insights and led to the solution to my problem. More than often, Stackoverflow shows me the right direction in many ways. In this case, I got a new idea from your answer and it worked. I thank you for that! 
And, I just don't care about the people downvoting questions like this: they may look stupid, but insight from others gives a lot more and educates!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure why `in_array` would be necessary really. if the `$id` is equal to the last item of the array, it can logically be assumed it's in the array. If one wanted to verify the `$id` was in the array and then determine if it's the last position (maybe do something else if it's not the last) it';d be necessary, but just the last position? [Produces the same results](http://codepad.org/tEi195lc).

Comment: @DACrosby That'd be a safe bet, sure. However, it's hard to know for sure what the OP wants to use this for. They must have a reason for using `in_array()`.